# Passing files to javac

Tags: java, javac

I was told that sometimes it is absolutely necessary to pass to `javac` several java files at once, in order for a program (consisting of several files) to compile successfully.

Or, perhaps, I've misunderstood and it was `java.tools.JavaCompiler` to whom it is sometimes necessary to pass several files at once.

Either way, I do not know if this is true or not. I thought passing `*.java` files one by one, with proper classpath, is always sufficient.

Could someone, please, explain?

Comment: If you have a one-file program, why would you need multiple files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files represent custom classes that may be true if they one (or multiple) are inter-dependent. When they are you must pass them to the compiler all at once, or compilation will fail.

```
class A {
  B b = new B();
  void do() {
    b.play();
  }
}

class B {
  A a = new A();
  void play() {
    System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```

Will not compile without `A` and `B` being available at compile time. The keyword in your first paragraph is *sometimes*.

Answer (score 3):

If you have two classes that each depend on each other, then compiling either one in isolation will fail.

```
public class ClassOne
{
    ClassTwo classTwo;
}

public class ClassTwo
{
    ClassOne classOne;
}
```

Each of them compiled in isolation will get a "cannot find symbol" error, because the other class isn't compiled yet.

Compiling both together in one command will compile both classes successfully, e.g.

```
javac *.java
```